# to post image file in windows phone 7 application

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

I am developing an application for windows phone 7.From here I want to upload an image file  to the remote server.I am using the following code to receive the file at my receiving end:

```
if (Request.Files.Count > 0)
{
    string UserName = Request.QueryString["SomeString"].ToString();
    HttpFileCollection MyFilecollection = Request.Files;           
    string ImageName = System.Guid.NewGuid().ToString() + MyFilecollection[0].FileName;   
    MyFilecollection[0].SaveAs(Server.MapPath("~/Images/" + ImageName));
}
```

Now my problem is, how can I post the file from my windows phone 7 platform (using PhotoChooserTask).I have tried the following code but with no success.(the following code is called from the PhotoChooserTask completed event handler.

```
private void UploadFile(string fileName, Stream data)
{
    char[] ch=new char[1];
    ch[0] = '\\';
    string [] flname=fileName.Split(ch);

    UriBuilder ub = new UriBuilder("http://www.Mywebsite.com?SomeString="+ussi );
    ub.Query = string.Format("name={0}", flname[6]);
    WebClient c = new WebClient();
    c.OpenWriteCompleted += (sender, e) =>
    {
        PushData(data, e.Result);
        e.Result.Close();
        data.Close();
    };
    c.OpenWriteAsync(ub.Uri);
}

private void PushData(Stream input, Stream output)
{
    byte[] buffer = new byte[4096];
    int bytesRead;
    while ((bytesRead = input.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) != 0)
    {
        output.Write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
    }
}
```

Please help me out to get out from this problem.
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I was able to get this working, but not using the Files collection.  From my post at http://chriskoenig.net/2011/08/19/upload-files-from-windows-phone/:

Client Code

```
public partial class MainPage : PhoneApplicationPage
{
    // Constructor
    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void SelectButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        PhotoChooserTask task = new PhotoChooserTask();
        task.Completed += task_Completed;
        task.Show();
    }

    private void task_Completed(object sender, PhotoResult e)
    {
        if (e.TaskResult != TaskResult.OK)
            return;

        const int BLOCK_SIZE = 4096;

        Uri uri = new Uri("http://localhost:4223/File/Upload", UriKind.Absolute);

        WebClient wc = new WebClient();
        wc.AllowReadStreamBuffering = true;
        wc.AllowWriteStreamBuffering = true;

        // what to do when write stream is open
        wc.OpenWriteCompleted += (s, args) =>
        {
            using (BinaryReader br = new BinaryReader(e.ChosenPhoto))
            {
                using (BinaryWriter bw = new BinaryWriter(args.Result))
                {
                    long bCount = 0;
                    long fileSize = e.ChosenPhoto.Length;
                    byte[] bytes = new byte[BLOCK_SIZE];
                    do
                    {
                        bytes = br.ReadBytes(BLOCK_SIZE);
                        bCount += bytes.Length;
                        bw.Write(bytes);
                    } while (bCount < fileSize);
                }
            }
        };

        // what to do when writing is complete
        wc.WriteStreamClosed += (s, args) =>
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Send Complete");
        };

        // Write to the WebClient
        wc.OpenWriteAsync(uri, "POST");
    }
}
```

Server Code

```
public class FileController : Controller
{
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Upload()
    {
        string filename = Server.MapPath("/Uploads/" + Path.GetRandomFileName();
        try
        {
            using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(filename), FileMode.Create))
            {
                using (BinaryWriter bw = new BinaryWriter(fs))
                {
                    using (BinaryReader br = new BinaryReader(Request.InputStream))
                    {
                        long bCount = 0;
                        long fileSize = br.BaseStream.Length;
                        const int BLOCK_SIZE = 4096;
                        byte[] bytes = new byte[BLOCK_SIZE];
                        do
                        {
                            bytes = br.ReadBytes(BLOCK_SIZE);
                            bCount += bytes.Length;
                            bw.Write(bytes);
                        } while (bCount < fileSize);
                    }
                }
            }

            return Json(new { Result = "Complete" });
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return Json(new { Result = "Error", Message = ex.Message });
        }
    }
}
```

Note that I'm using ASP.NET MVC to receive my file, but you should be able to use the same, core logic with WebForms.

/chris